# Implement space in HTML

Tags: html, firefox, space

How do I implement a white space (to put between links) in HTML ?

Bruno

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Common answer: Use a non-breaking space, which is generally written as a HTML entitity `&nbsp;`

CSS answer: Add padding or margin to the links in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 3):

You can use html code `&nbsp;` This will create a non breaking space, you can add multiple ones

But i suggest you use CSS for positioning.

Comment: that's `&nbsp;`, not `&nbps`... but it's an easy typo to make  :)

Answer (score 2):

Set white-space to Preserve using CSS: http://xhtml.com/en/css/reference/white-space/

Answer (score 0):

Try using a non-breaking space: `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set left and right margins using css. Although vertical margins won't work if the link is being displayed inline (which it is by default).